# VBA Countifs over 500k Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large table that I've put in a pivot table, but I'd like to get a unique count so I'm trying to set up a helper column on the side that is 1 / unique count, so in the pivot it sums back to 1. The formula I have is:

1/COUNTIFS(B2:B460489,B2,I2:I460489,I2)

This should work, but since I have almost 500k rows it is taking ages to calculate. I've also tried to do the calculation in VBA in the hopes it would be faster, but still took >10 min before I exited it.

Is there anyway to make this calculation more manageable?

based on the idea to use an array, I've come up with the below code using a double loop, because for each row in the table I need to know how many times that store/product occurred in the whole table. Its still too slow though, is it possible to make it more efficient?

```
arr = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:AH" & lr)

ReDim Arr2(UBound(arr) - 1, 0)

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Ans = 0
    For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(j, 2) = arr(i, 2) And arr(j, 9) = arr(i, 9) Then 'And arr(j, 33) = 1 Then
            Ans = Ans + 1
        End If
    Next j
    If Ans > 0 Then
        arr(i, 34) = 1 / Ans
        Arr2(i - 1, 0) = arr(i, 34)
    End If
Next i

Sheets("Data").Range("AH2:AH" & lr) = Arr2
```

Comment: A unique count of *what*? If you are going for a VBA solution maybe ditch the helper column and describe the problem more directly.

Comment: I have a sheet with products stocked across stores per week. Column B is the stores, column I is the products. I need the helper column so that in the pivot table with the rest of my calculations the sum of that formula will come back to 1.

by that the formula is 1 / Countifs(Stores, particular store, Products, particular product)

so if a product is in a store for all 13 weeks of data in my table, the formula will be 1 / 13, and in my pivot it should sum them all back to 1

Comment: Do it in VBA. Stick all of your rows to be calculated into an Array, calculate the array and post the answer. By doing it in memory instead of reading from the sheet it makes the process a lot faster.

Comment: that's a great idea, could you give me a quick explanation of how to do a countifs in an array? I've only worked a bit with arrays and not to do that

Comment: So what do you want to display in your pivot table? What will be in the rows/columns/data area?

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to use an array to achieve this. I've used 4 columns similar to what you described but not exact so you'll need to change it a bit. If you can give me a clearer description of what's going on I can update this to be exact to your issue if needs be.

[image: Example Layout]

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
    Dim ans As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim arr() as variant

    arr = Range("B2:J8")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 2) = 1 And arr(i, 9) = "Fruit" Then
            ans = ans + 1
        End If
    Next i

    If ans > 0 Then
        MsgBox 1 / ans
    Else
        MsgBox "Division by 0 error"
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will set your range to the array (you will need to change the range to suit yours. I'd recommend putting your entire usedrange into the array in case of any other calculations that you'd want to do). It will then test each entry in the array if it matches the if conditional. and then add 1 to it as a count.

Comment: I think this will work, but I had to make a double loop because I want to know the count of each product / store in the whole array. I've updated my question with the code I have so far

Comment: How long is it taking now?

Comment: It ran for 10 minutes then my excel crashed, I was hoping to find a way to do this in a few minutes but maybe that's not possible?

Comment: Have you thought about moving it to something like sql?

Comment: don't have any experience with SQL, that might be a good idea I'll look in to that